# Nested Loops Using Loop Macro in Common Lisp

Tags: loops, macros, nested, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to implement a basic nested loop in CL, but the Loop macro is resisting this. Basically, I would like to find all possible products of 3-digit numbers and accumulate them into a list.

Here is my attempt:

```
 (loop for x downfrom 999 to 998 do (loop for y downfrom 999 to 998 collect (* x y)))
```

The code above returns `NIL` for some reason. By the way, I realize that I only run down to 998, but this is done for testing purposes.

What could I do to obtain a list like this:

> (999*999 999*998 ... 998*998 998*997 ... 997*997 997*996 ... 100*100)

Comment: Peter Seibel gives an overview of LOOP: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/loop-for-black-belts.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `COLLECT`-clause in the inner loop doesn't affect the outer loop. So the inner loop returns a list of results, but the `DO`-clause in the outer loop just discards the result. You should use `APPEND` or `NCONC` instead of `DO`. Usually it's better to just stick with `APPEND` if there are no performance concerns, even if in this case `NCONC` would be safe.

```
(loop for x downfrom 999 to 900
      append (loop for y downfrom 999 to 900
                   collect (* x y)))
```

Comment: Magic! Much appreciated!

Comment: I am still getting used to reading CL's docs and they can be confusing at times.

Comment: @MadPhysicist w.r.t. the CLHS LOOP pages, that's a _mild_ understatement, isn't it. :)

Comment: @WillNess Yes, a mild one haha :-)