# Can you help me understand a few aspects of this tic-tac-toe minimax code? (Specifics within)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I’m trying to teach myself minimax in javscript from the code here: https://github.com/beaucarnes/fcc-project-tutorials/blob/master/tictactoe/7/script.js

And video: https://youtu.be/P2TcQ3h0ipQ?t=2334

This is the function:

```
function minimax(newBoard, player) {
    var availSpots = emptySquares();

    if (checkWin(newBoard, huPlayer)) {
        return {score: -10};
    } else if (checkWin(newBoard, aiPlayer)) {
        return {score: 10};
    } else if (availSpots.length === 0) {
        return {score: 0};
    }
    var moves = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++) {
        var move = {};
        move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];
        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

        if (player == aiPlayer) {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        } else {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        }

        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;
        moves.push(move);
    }

    var bestMove;
    if(player === aiPlayer) {
        var bestScore = -10000;
        for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
            if (moves[i].score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = moves[i].score;
                bestMove = i;
            }
        }
    } else {
        var bestScore = 10000;
        for(var i = 0; i < moves.length; i++) {
            if (moves[i].score < bestScore) {
                bestScore = moves[i].score;
                bestMove = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return moves[bestMove];
}
```

I think I understand most of it, but there are a few gaps preventing me from getting my mind around it completely.

As I understand it, `minimax(newBoard, player)` starts by getting the available spots from which to play a move, and establishing a way of ranking the end results.

Then it creates an array `moves` into which objects called `move` will go. The for loop gets a `move` object for each available spot.

Each `move` object gets a property called index through `move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];`

- Does `newBoard[availSpots[i]]` simply represent the indexes of the
  available sorts. Is it right to say that in a board that has
  available spots `[4, 5, 6]`, `newBoard[availSpots[0]]` is `4` and
  thus the first move object will have an index property of 4?

  The new part of code is `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player` -- does
  that mean the player's icon is marked in `newBoard[4]`?

After that, there is an `if else` statement that adds a `.score` property to the `move` object.

- But then I see `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index`, which reverses
  what we did earlier -- why is this?

Then the latest move is pushed into the `moves` array, and from the array, we loop through the scores to find the `best move` of moves.

I'm having a hard time seeing how this all works. I tried putting in a console.log and my repl.it fails...

- is it because dozens of permutations are being tried by the compiler
  and it would be ugly to have them all logged? How many moves does the
  computer have to try?

And finally:

- Since this is a turn-based game, where in the code is the computer
  "playing" the other side in order to get a terminal value?

I've gone through a ton of minimax resources online so I'm hoping someone can help -- they all seem to gloss over this. I've looked at:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-tic-tac-toe-game-unbeatable-by-using-the-minimax-algorithm-9d690bad4b37/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-1-introduction/

https://youtu.be/trKjYdBASyQ

https://youtu.be/ovr2sTYhb1I

https://learnersbucket.com/tutorials/js-projects/tic-tac-toe-game-in-javascript-with-bot/

https://steveafrost.com/articles/discovering-the-minimax-algorithm/

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with your last question.

> Since this is a turn-based game, where in the code is the computer "playing" the other side in order to get a terminal value?

It's not, not in this code.  This function has one purpose, to choose the best move using the minimax algorithm.  It does so by manipulating a board object, setting values and resetting them, finding the score of the position.  Other code must handle the IO.  So it's important to keep in mind that this code is just part of an overall tic-tac-toe system.

This understanding might help clear up some of the other questions.

> Is it right to say that in a board that has available spots `[4, 5, 6]`, `newBoard[availSpots[0]]` is `4` and thus the first move object will have an index property of 4?

While you can think of it that way, there's nothing in this code to describe *how* the board is represented.  So, while it might be squares `1` - `9`, it doesn't have to be.  they could be `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3`.  Or there could be another representation altogether.  What we do know is that the the board has some properties we can reference with `[]` (numbers, strings, possibly even Symbols) and that `availSpots` is an array of these values.  Clearly it represents the ones that are available.

> The new part of code is `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player` -- does that mean the player's icon is marked in `newBoard[4]`?

It means that the internal data structure of the board now identifies that player with the given cell.  Again, this code is only for choosing the best move.  But it knows nothing about icons or the visible representation of the board.  And note that this state of the board is transitory; the manipulation of the board is meant only to help calculate the best move.  Other code would actually apply the move it calculates to the board in progress.

> After that, there is an `if else` statement that adds a `.score` property to the `move` object.
>
> But then I see `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index`, which reverses what we did earlier -- why is this?

It is testing the board, available move by available move, to find the best one.  It does this by making a move, calculating the resulting score and then resetting that move so it can try a different one.  In calculating the move, we might recursively call back to `minmax`, which will then try *its* moves sequentially, and this could extend as many as nine layers deep, one for each cell on the board.

Thus if the current board looks like

```
X O O
4 5 6
X O X
```

We would get the following analysis:

```
         max    min    max
X O O
4 5 6
X O X
  |     X O O
  +-->  X 5 6  (score 10)
  |     X O X
  |
  |     X O O
  +-->  4 X 6  (score 10)
  |     X O X
  |
  |     X O O
  +-->  4 5 X
        X O X
          |    X O O
          +--> O 5 X
          |    X O X
          |      |    X O O
          |      +--> O X O  (score 10)
          |           X O X
          |     
          +--> X O O
               4 O X  (score -10)
               X O X
```

We try available move `4` for `X`, find that its score would be `+10`, *then reset `4` to its default*, so that we can try `5` for `X`, scored also as `10`.  Again we reset `5` to its default.  Then we try `6` for `X`.  To score that, we have to go deeper, first trying `4` for `O`. This requires us to go deeper still and we set `5` to `X`.  That has value `+10`.  We reset that, reset the `4` and try again with `5` for `O`, which has a score of `-10`. Following minimax, we can find that the value of `X O O / 4 5 X / X O X` is `-10`, and we'd already seen that both `X O O / X 5 6 / X O X` and `X O O / 4 X 6 / X O X` have score of `+10`, so we'd choose one of those.  (By this algorithm, the first one, but a more interesting algorithm might choose randomly among the equally good moves.)

> I tried putting in a console.log and my repl.it fails...
>
> is it because dozens of permutations are being tried by the compiler and it would be ugly to have them all logged? How many moves does the computer have to try?

We'd have to see what you did to test this, but no, this game is simple enough that you should never be running out of any resources in these calculations.  There are fewer than `9!` -- which is `362880` -- total games.  So I'm guessing you weren't logging correctly.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed response! I know my question was pretty involved, so I'm grateful for any response at all, but especially I'm so for some thing as thoughtful as what you wrote.  

You helped me clear up a few things, on the turn and the way the algorithm works.

But I'm still having a little trouble envisioning the mechanics of it all, which I put in another answer this post. Can you spare some thoughts on that as well?

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code:

```
    var moves = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < availSpots.length; i++) {
        var move = {};
        move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];
        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player;

        if (player == aiPlayer) {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        } else {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        }

        newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index;
        moves.push(move);
    }
```

To follow from the great map you drew out:

We get an array called `moves` and then starting from the first entry in `availSpots` which is `[4,5,6]`, we create an object called `move`

`move.index = newBoard[availSpots[i]];` means the index property of `move` is 4.

So I can envision this: `var move = {index:4}`

And then we have: `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = player`

Which means `newBoard = X, O, O, X, 5, 6, X, O, X`

Then following the `if` statement, we get `var move = {index:4, score:10};`

And finally, `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index` means going back to original state:

`newBoard = X, O, O, 4, 5, 6, X, O, X`

And upon pushing `moves.push(move)`:

We get `moves = [move {index:4 score:10}};]`

As i = 1 in the `for` loop, we wind up with
`moves = [move {index:4 score:10}}, move {index:5 score:10}};]`

But my understanding falls apart here. If i = 2, `var move = {index:6}`

Then, `newBoard = X, O, O, 4, 5, X, X, O, X`

However, `var move = {index:6}` does not yield a terminal value, so what is the code doing from this point forward?

The code tells us:

```
if (player == aiPlayer) {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, huPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        } else {
            var result = minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
            move.score = result.score;
        }
```

But there is no score at this point as there is no terminal value. I know the `else` statement must be executed because `newBoard` is not going to original state `newBoard = X, O, O, 4, 5, 6, X, O, X` yet, this will not be executed yet: `newBoard[availSpots[i]] = move.index`

So minimax is called on `newBoard = X, O, O, 4, 5, X, X, O, X`, and there is a new `availSpots`, which is `[4,5]`. This time `player` is O because elsewhere in the code, `player` changes after the board has been checked, so `newBoard = X, O, O, O, 5, X, X, O, X`.

There is no terminal value for `newBoard = X, O, O, O, 5, X, X, O, X` either, so the process begins again at the `if` statement.

- Is it fair to say only when there is a score, can the line after
  `minimax` be executed, `move.score = result.score` and the code can
  continue to push the `move` to the array?

There's a lot of unsaid interleaving going on here which makes it hard for me to get my mind around things.

At the initial point, when the board had 3 available spaces, not only do two spots (4 and 5) would have a terminal value, but to get the terminal value for spot 6, the code would have to calculate the best choice in an array of 2 available spaces.

The longer it takes to reach a terminal value, the greater the number of paths. And before you get to the optimal move for you, the code has to calculate the optimal move for all the other choices leading up to it.

- After the first move, I guess the code has to go through 8! or 40320
  games and I guess it would go faster the closer to the end we get?
  Where would be a good place to put a `console.log` to see what's
  going on under the hood?
- There's a lot that goes unsaid in the code. For example, that if
  `minimax()` fails to return a score, it keeps doing so for the other
  side, and that there are multiple sets of the `moves` array being
  generated for every available space before the terminal value is
  found. How does someone think all of this through, when
  `console.log`-ing would be overwhelming?

I built my tic-tac-toe board on my own, so I was hoping by learning the thought process behind this `minimax()`, I could make some tweaks and applying it to my own, but it's harder than it looks.

- Finally, in the calculation of `var bestMove` here the latest
  `moves[i].score` replaces the previous best score, is it safe to
  assume the code would play the first optimal move that it encounters,
  and never one in the middle, because those moves might equal, but
  never fulfill `if (moves[i].score > bestScore) {bestScore = moves[i].score}`?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I find useful the analogy between recursion and mathematical induction.  I described it in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65602041/1243641). Also, a debugger --  especially with conditional breakpoints -- would probably be much easier than `console.log`.

Comment: You should also be able to debug this function with a sample board that already has many moves applied.  My example in a separate answer only tests a total of seven boards, so if you can build that board data-structure with the given moves already supplied, you can probably use multiple logging calls without any issues.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still struggling with recursion but I think I worked out another way into this minimax function. I can evaluate simply, choosing between two options at the end of the game, but when the answer takes several levels, I fall apart. Is there a debugger you would recommend? I only know how to use `console.log`

Comment: As far as a sample board goes, indeed, good idea! Prior to working on the minimax, I had built the tic-tac-toe game with an option to play against another player or completely random opponent, so I was able to input a board until the last 3 squares as a human-to-human game and then `console.log` around the last three moves to get a better idea of what's going on. It still gets very slow with the initial choice of nine boxes though!

Comment: I'm surprised it's overly slow.  But I haven't tested or really thought it through deeply, Of course, you can always randomly make the first move (it's better user experience anyway), and that should cut the time significantly.