# Missing pattern in inserts function

Tags: haskell, ghci, non-exhaustive-patterns, multiline-repl-definition

I have this function `inserts` where

```
inserts 1 [2,3] = [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```

here's the definition (straight from Algorithm Design with Haskell by Bird and Gibbons)

```
inserts :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
inserts x [] = [[x]]
inserts x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (inserts x ys)
```

I've tried it in ghci with the example above, but I get the following exception

```
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3]*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-53: Non-exhaustive patterns in function inserts
```

Does anyone know what is the missing pattern?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines

Comment: inserts n = zipWith (\xs ys -> xs <> (n:ys)) <$> inits <*> tails

Comment: i.e. `inserts n xs = [ a ++ n:b | (a,b) <- zip (inits xs) (tails xs) ]`

Comment: also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65996009/849891) is related to the subject matter (not the error). (disclaimer, it is written by me).

Answer (score 7):

When I define `inserts` as per your code and then run `inserts 1 [2,3]`, I don’t get any error, and the correct result is returned. However, I can replicate the error when I do this:

```
Prelude> inserts x [] = [[x]]
Prelude> inserts x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (inserts x ys)
Prelude>
Prelude> inserts 1 [2,3]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3]*** Exception: <interactive>:2:1-53: Non-exhaustive patterns in function inserts
```

So the issue is not your function. Rather, you are inputting it into GHCi incorrectly. When you enter a multiline function into GHCi like this, it instead defines *two* functions rather than one: first it defines `inserts x [] = [[x]]`, and then it overwrites this definition with `inserts x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (inserts x ys)`. The correct method of entering a multiline function into GHCi is instead by surrounding the definition with `:{` `:}`:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| inserts :: a -> [a] -> [[a]]
Prelude| inserts x [] = [[x]]
Prelude| inserts x (y:ys) = (x:y:ys) : map (y:) (inserts x ys)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> inserts 1 [2,3]
[[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[2,3,1]]
```